# Disconnect Mapped Drive If Not Part of an AD Group

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, network-drive, gpo

On Windows 2012R2 Essentials:

I use GPO to map a network drive from a NAS device based on AD Group Membership.

The mapping works fine but when I delete a user from the AD Group that has access to the share the drive stays mapped but the user does not have access any more.

How can I automatically disconnect the mapped drive if the user does not have access anymore?

I tried using a logon script with:

```
net use * /d /y
```

but it runs after the GPO and it also deletes user's Home Drive (which is setup under profile in AD)

Answer (score 0):

You should map drive without "persistent" parameter. After policy refresh mapped drive disappears.

Comment: I have unchecked "Reconnect" option and left the Action with the "Update" setting. Still have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention that this maps them via GPO, then all you need to do is change the properties of the Drive Mappings.

[image: GPO Drive Map Options]

Also, ensure that the Action is Replace. Then it will only apply for as long as the user is in the group.